# Custom email address with AWS

Tags: amazon-sns, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

There are a few solutions for this problem:

1. Using workmail
2. Using zoho free tier
3. setting up an ec2 email server
4. ses /s3 combination

I am following the tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/responsetap-engineering/easily-create-email-addresses-for-your-route53-custom-domain-589d099dd0f2)

This is what I have:

1. domain: example.com(verified) & email: scilla@example.com
2. Rule Set
3. Rule with recipient scilla@example.com with action SNS topic example_email
4. personal_email subscribed to sns topic example_email
5. Resend verification

I've got the confirmation that my email is subscribed to the sns topic. I can see the status is confirmed in the Subscriptions and the topic is example_email.

After I configured scilla@example.com with action to SNS topic example_email and subscribed personal_email to topic example_email, I would expect to receive the verification when I resend it.

The verification is pending.

How could I debug this problem?
Am I missing any steps?
Do I need special configuration in Route53?

Note: I was able to verify my personal email with SES.

Comment: There is no need to verify a single email address since you have the entire domain already verifyied in SES.

Comment: so, what would be a solution for me to use scilla@example.com as my email?
there is no need but the problem still persists.

Comment: What's the problem besides the pending verification?

Comment: well, I am not sure what I need to do next? I was assuming that aws would let me send emails from the console using my custom domain. Or I could have a password to add my email to outlook or whatever client i would want?

this is my end goal: Email Addresses for your Route53 Custom Domain

Comment: You can enter the SMTP username and password to the email client. Then you will be able to send emails as `scilla@example.com`.

Comment: how would i do that. do you have a solid documentation?

Comment: even so, my problem is not solved. I need to solve why the verification is not sent to my personal email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial works fine.

To be mentioned: you'll only be able to set the rules in 3 [AZ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html)

This system can be treated as a notification system.
If you send an email to that address, you'll get just the title of the email, not the content.